# Cannot resolve hostname?

Tags: dns, hostname

I' using lucid 10.04 i used centrify agent to add my ubuntu machine into AD. The machine name is suppose to be abc.company.edu.uk.

I have edited /etc/hosts file. It says as 
192.168.1.22  abc.company.edu.uk abc.

In etc/resolve.conf i have specified dns servers. Do i need to change anything in nsswitch.conf files. When i try to ping from other lan pc to abc.company.edu.pk i get no reply?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to edit /etc/hosts on each machine that will connect *to* your abc.company.edu.uk machine, as well as on the machine itself. That file is not used to advertise a computer's name across a network.

If you want to advertise the computer name without editing anything on the other computers, you would need to use a proper DNS setup.

Comment: and how can i do proper dns setup? please inform.

Comment: Please see any of the Related questions in the right-hand sidebar  ->